# BigQuery API limit exceeded error

Tags: google-bigquery

We've got error during tabledata.list with message:

```
API limit exceeded: Unable to return a row that exceeds the API limits. To retrieve the row, export the table.
```

It is not listed at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#errortable .

This error occurs every time.

We can export this table into GCS normally. Result looks normal (there are no extremely large rows).

We manage to retrieve several result pages before the actual error occurs.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "API limit exceeded: Unable to return a row that exceeds the API limits. To retrieve the row, export the table.",
    "reason" : "apiLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "API limit exceeded: Unable to return a row that exceeds the API limits. To retrieve the row, export the table."
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145) ~[com.google.api-client.google-api-client-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113) ~[com.google.api-client.google-api-client-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40) ~[com.google.api-client.google-api-client-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321) ~[com.google.api-client.google-api-client-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
```

What does it mean? How can we resolve this error?

Comment: I got the following error when running bq query with CLI:   

BigQuery error in query operation: API limit exceeded: Unable to return a row that exceeds the API limits. To retrieve the row, export the table.

bq --location=US query --destination_table dataset.table --replace --use_legacy_sql=false --allow_large_results --service_account_credential_file xxx.json --project_id yyyy  '<sql statement here>'

But, for the same SQL statement,  I could get it run in the Web interface.  Is there any way to work around this error in the CLI?

Answer (score 6):

Sorry about the inconvenience.

This is a known issue of tabledata.list method.
The problem is that we have some infrastructure limitations that it is currently not possible to return very *large* row from tabledata.list.

*large* is a relative word. Unfortunately some row has small size when represented in json, but can consume lots of memory when represented in our internal format.

The current workaround is as mentioned in the error message: to export the table.

For the long-term, we are actively working on improving our system to overcome this limitation. Stay tuned :)

Comment: Could you reveal a bit more?

So, I've export this table. This "bad" row is in export, is not it?

It seems, that issue is not with regular data types (like Int/String). BTW, longest string is 5Kb in that table (40+ fields). 

We have 2 repeated fields (Strings) in our schema. The biggest contains 27 repeated values, in total 450 bytes.

We'd like to introduce reasonable limitation before writing into BQ. But we don't have any ideas, what "reasonable" is.

Comment: @cheng-miezianko is this issue already solved? Because one of the first links that appear on Google for "schemata rate limit exceeded" is this one and idk if what I'm facing is still a result from this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are two row related limits for tabledata.list:

1. The byte size of the proto message has to be less than 10M. If one row is larger than this size, we cannot retrieve it.
2. The max field value in the row has to be less than 350,000, that is the number of leaf fields of a row.

If you hit that problem, it usually only means the first row in your request is too large to return, if you skip that row, the following row retrieval might work. You may try look at the particular row closer to see why.

In the future, it is likely the field value limit can be removed, but we will still have the 10M size limit due to API server limitations.

Comment: Is there a way to skip rows that exceed API limit?