# Unable to return a row that exceeds the API limits

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am facing the below error when I run a query from BigQuery UI or use it in Dataflow. The table has many columns, some are records, normal string, integer, and nested columns. Three columns are string in which I am storing JSON data. Initially, as the error shows I thought it is because some row size is more than the BigQuery max Limit, so I tried to check 3 JSON columns and found that the byte length of one row's column is 4599, rest all were around 3000. I tried to select only that row(big row) and insert it in another table but that individual row did not give any issue and got selected properly from the query so this proved my theory wrong that it is because of row size else single row would have also given that error.

I excluded that row from overall result of the query and ran the query so everything worked for some time, but later the same query again gave **the row exceeds limit error.**

I want to know why this error is coming and how I reproduce it every time. is it related to the overall usage of BigQuery as whenever this error comes, BigQuery was busy processing heavy load.

I even exported the result in another table, but if I query that table then also I get this error.

**Error:-**

`failed to establish a connection due to 400 GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/******: API limit exceeded: Unable to return a row that exceeds the API limits. To retrieve the row, export the table.`

Please help if anyone is aware of it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547711/bigquery-api-limit-exceeded-error

Comment: @ Felipe Hoffa, quick question I have seen that thread but it does not help in answering a question like how I figure out the problematic row. Somehow I am not able to figure out that row and it does not show up anywhere. can you please help me with that?